# How do I prevent the water in an automatic fish farm freezing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built an automatic fish farm in an Ice Plains biome (which I now realise was the worst idea) and the water keeps freezing, even though I placed torches above it as [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169352/how-to-prevent-water-from-freezing) suggests (although I believe this only melts ice, rather than prevents it from forming).

I can't place a block above the water to stop it freezing because fish farms require direct sunlight access.

[image: Fish farm]

**How can I prevent the water from freezing?**

Comment: I'd like to +1 the point that building anything using water in an 'icy/snowy' biome is a terrible idea. Not bashing on you, just my two cents

Comment: Considering your own self-answer; how is this not a duplicate of the question you linked? The answer is the same (torches or other light source, or a block above the water). Incidentally, I suspect the torches aren't preventing the water from freezing because they are 1 block higher than the example used in the other question, which puts the water *just* out of the torches' 'prevent freezing' range.

Comment: @David I now totally agree

Comment: @TrentHawkins This question refers to fish farms specifically - no blocks except glass would work. The torches may be out of range but, according to the linked question, I believe they don't prevent freezing - they just melt already frozen blocks

Comment: @David: Allow me to disagree; icy/snow biome is optimal for an ice farm, and it definitely involves water.

Comment: @SF. My confidence is shattered, lmao, good point :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that placing a glass block above the water prevents the water freezing while letting sunlight through

[image: Fish farm with glass block]

Answer (score 3):

> Water source blocks in a snowy biome will eventually freeze into ice if exposed to the sky from directly above, the light level immediately adjacent to the water block on all sides is less than 13, and there is at least one horizontally adjacent non-water block.

Glass above work if it doesn't conflict with the farm geometry. Another simple option is a torch, immediately adjacent to the water.